# How to scrape specific google weather text with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How would I be able to find the class text "New York City, New York, USA" in `Python` with `BeautifulSoup`?

Was trying to replicate a video for practicing but it doesnt work anymore.

Tried finding something in the official documentation but didnt get it to work. Or is my get_html_content function not working properly and Google just blocks me thus returning an empty `list` / `None` ?

**Here's my current code:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def get_html_content(city):
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT
    session.headers['Accept-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    session.headers['Content-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    city.replace(" ", "+")
    html_content = session.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+in+{city}").text
    return html_content

def home(request):
    result = None
    if 'city' in request.GET: 
        city = request.GET.get('city')
        html_content = get_html_content(city)
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
        soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'wob_loc q8U8x'})
        **OR**
        soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'wob_loc'})
```

--> both return empty lists (= `.find` method returns `None`)

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the google page has probable changed in the meantime, so to get data about the weather you have to change your code. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


params = {'q':'weather in New York City, New York, USA', 'hl': 'en'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0'}
cookies = {'CONSENT':"YES+cb.20220419-08-p0.cs+FX+111"}

url = 'https://www.google.com/search'


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.select('#wob_dp [aria-label]'):
    how = t.find_next('img')['alt']
    temp = t.find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<5} {:<20} {}'.format(t.text, how, temp))
```

Prints:

```
Mon   Sunny                8
Tue   Cloudy               7
Wed   Partly cloudy        11
Thu   Rain                 7
Fri   Mostly cloudy        8
Sat   Partly cloudy        6
Sun   Scattered showers    8
Mon   Showers              8
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to select the elements is not necessarily wrong, it would work as long as the `soup` is based on the rendered version of the web page, which you can get for example by using `selenium`.

Your approach, however, uses `requests` which cannot render the dynamic content in the same way as a browser would, so instead you have to make do with the static content.

First of all, you should also send a `consent cookie` with your request so that you can access the desired content (This means that your assumption is already going in the right direction):

```
cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'}
```

and then you should use the HTML structure to select the elements.

##### Example (`requests`)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html_content(city):
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT
    session.headers['Accept-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    session.headers['Content-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    city.replace(" ", "+")
    html_content = session.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+in+{city}", cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'}).text
    return html_content

html_content = get_html_content('New York City, New York, USA')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)

soup.select_one('div>span>span')
```

##### Example (`selenium`)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+inNew%20York%20City,%20New%20York,%20USA'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'wob_loc'})
```